# Checking for protected mode in Lua C

Tags: lua

In a Lua C handler I set a flag in the registry before throwing an error. I'd like to ensure that this flag is set (or cleared) if the handler is called from Lua with `pcall`. Here are more details:

I have a basic Lua function `handle` called from C using `lua_pcall`:

```
function handle()
  c_handle()
end
```

The handle in C has the basic structure below in which we want to set a flag before throwing an error to distinguish the error from others.

```
int c_handle(lua_State *L)
{
  if (condition) {
    set a flag in registry
    throw error with lua_error
}
```

The problem I'm having is I'd like to either not set the registry flag, or clear it, if Lua is calling the handler with pcall:

```
function handle()
  pcall(c_handle)
end
```

Comment: Are you able to replace `pcall` with your own version?

Answer (score 1):

You could sandbox the scripts and replace `pcall` with your own version that would call back to `c_handle()`, like so:

```
local newenv = {
    pcall = function(f, arg1, arg2, ...)
        if pcall(f, arg1, arg2, ...) then
            c_handle(true) -- no error, pass true to c_handle
        else
            c_handle(false) -- error, pass false to c_handle
        end if
    end
}
setmetatable(newenv, {__index = _G})
setfenv(1, newenv)
```

So now when you do a protected call, it'll go through `c_handle`.

**EDIT**

Not too sure on the syntax for passing a parameter to a C function, but that would be the basic gist of it, I suppose.

Comment: The flag set in c_handle needs to be reset if pcall catches an error. So, I think in this case the pcall wrapper needs to be C.

Comment: @NoahWatkins Not at all, `pcall` returns false on error, so all you have to do is send a flag through c_handle, although now the call to c_handle would be made after the `pcall`. Easy to change though, call `c_handle`, store the `pcall` return value in a variable and call your C function for the flag. Not sure on the exact syntax to send a parameter to a C function, but I'd expect it to be similar to a regular function call. I've edited my post a bit to reflect this.

Comment: Ahh, implicit in my comment was that I don't want to expose this functionality through the c_handler interface.. Is there a way to have the version of c_handler with the flag exposed only be accecssible from the pcall wrapper?

Comment: @NoahWatkins Short of writing the handler in Lua or setting the flag via Lua, I don't think you can. You could make the handler require a key of sorts, but as far as I know, that's the only workaround.